# How to convert an array with objects that contain value,values to a single object with only key,values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce

So after drawing data for the database I ended up with something like

```
[
{name: "id", data_type: "integer"}
{name: "name", data_type: "char"}
{name: "active", data_type: "boolean"}
]
```

but what I want is:

```
{id: "integer" , name: "char" , active: "boolean" }
```

I tried a bunch of things but couldn't figured it out, any helps would be appreciated

This is my desperate attempt:

```
Object.entries(jsonData).map((type) => {
        return { ...objectList, [type[1].name]: type[1].data_type };
      }).reduce((objectList, object) => (
          ...objectList,
          object)
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple approach:

```js
let arr = [
{name: "id", data_type: "integer"},
{name: "name", data_type: "char"},
{name: "active", data_type: "boolean"}
];
let map = {};
arr.forEach(e => map[e.name]=e.data_type);
console.log(map);
```

If you want to use `.reduce`, try this:

```js
let arr = [
{name: "id", data_type: "integer"},
{name: "name", data_type: "char"},
{name: "active", data_type: "boolean"}
];
let map = arr.reduce(function(obj,item){
  obj[item.name] = item.data_type; 
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(map);
```

Comment: Thank you! the .reduce returned a bug for me but the .forEach works amazingly!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reduce

```js
const data = [
{name: "id", data_type: "integer"},
{name: "name", data_type: "char"},
{name: "active", data_type: "boolean"}
];

const arrayToObject = arr => arr.reduce((result, value) => {
  result[value.name] = value.data_type;
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(arrayToObject(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is using `Array.reduce()`

```js
const array = [
  { name: 'id', data_type: 'integer' },
  { name: 'name', data_type: 'char' },
  { name: 'active', data_type: 'boolean' },
];

const newObject = array.reduce((finalObj, obj) => {
  finalObj[obj.name] = obj.data_type;
  return finalObj;
}, {})

console.log(newObject)
```